# Explanation about solution for selecting $5$ out of $8$ integers and a pair adds to $9$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation, pigeonhole-principle

I am reading the following exercise in a section about the pigeohole principle.

> Show that if five integers are selected from the first 8 positive
> integers, there must be a pair of these integers with sum equal to $9   $

The solution states:

> Group the first 8 positive integers into four subsets of two integers,
> each so that the integers of each subset add up to $9$ i.e. {$1$,$8$},
> {$2$,$7$},{$3$,$6$},{$4$,$5$}. If five integers are selected by the
> first 8, then by the pigeonhole principle at least two of them come
> from the same subset

I don't understand the explanation. The $4$ subsets mentioned
are just one way to divide the $8$ positive integers. Another way would be {$1,7$}, {$2$,$8$}, {$3$,$5$}, {$4$,$6$} and  in that case the pigeonhole principle does not help.
So is the fact that there is *a* specific way to group the $8$ positive integers into $4$ groups and apply the pigeonhole principle a valid solution since it is not generic enough?

The way I read the exercise is that a random choice of $8$ positive integers leads to a pair that sums to $9$. So how is the fact that we can construct a specific way to group pairs (the way I read the solution) a correct solution if there are other ways to group them that don't sum to $9$? Doesn't the random selection imply any of the possible sub groupings is equally likely? Hence we could have {$1,7$}, {$2$,$8$}, {$3$,$5$}, {$4$,$6$}

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: The four pairs $\{1, 8\}, \{2, 7\}, \{3, 6\}, \{4, 5\}$ were chosen specifically so that choosing two elements from one of those pairs would guarantee that their sum is $9$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: But isn't this an artificial proof? Where in the exercise is it implied that any specific way of choosing is valid? I think I am misunderstanding something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the point.

Suppose that I try to choose $5$ numbers from $\{1,2,\cdots,8\}$ such that no two of the $5$ sum to $9$.

How should I do it?

One try is selecting the numbers $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.  However, this fails, because $4 + 5 = 9.$

So, I try to vary it.  I try $\{1,2,3,4,6\}$. This fails because $3 + 6 = 9.$

Then, I try $\{1,2,4,6,8\}$. This fails because $1 + 8 = 9.$

---

Then, I ask myself: is there some deeper pattern that is preventing me from succeeding.

I consider the following pairs of numbers:
$\{1,8\}$
$\{2,7\}$
$\{3,6\}$
$\{4,5\}$.

Then, I look at my $3$ failed attempts and I realized that the reason that they failed is that each attempt happened to select more than one number from one of the $4$ sets of numbers above.

So, then I ask myself: what do I have to do to select $5$ numbers such that no two of the numbers add up to $9$.  It is clear that I must not select more than one number from any of the $4$ sets of numbers above.

Then, the light dawns.  I am required to select **five** numbers.  If I only permit myself to select one number from each of the $4$ sets above, then I will have selected **at most** $4$ numbers.

This implies that when I go to select the $5$-th number, I will have no choice but to take the second number from one of the $4$ sets above.

Comment: So I guess the fact that there exists a way to group the numbers in pairs that sum to $9$ necessitates that we'll always select $5$ and among them $2$ will sum to $9$?

Comment: @Jim Yes, that's it.