# Circular table with $25$ boys and $25$ girls and someone always sitting among $2$ boys

Tags: combinatorics, proof-explanation, pigeonhole-principle

I am reading the following exercise in a section about Pigeonhole principle.

> Show that whenever $25$ girls and $25$ boys are seated around a
> circular table there is always a person both of whose neighbors are
> boys

I am confused with the solution presented which is the following:

> Number the seats around the table from $1$ to $50$. Hence we have $25$
> seats with odd numbers and $25$ seats with even numbers.   If no more
> than $12$ boys occupied the odd-numbered seats then at least $13$ boys
> would occupy the even-numbered seats and vice-versa. Without loss of
> generality, assume at least $13$ boys occupy the $25$ odd-numbered
> seats. Then at least $2$ of those boys must be in consecutive
> odd-numbered seats, and the person sitting between them will have boys
> as both of his/her neighbors

I don't understand:

1. how the "no more than $12$" is determined and
2. how do we know that if at least $13$ boys occupy the $25$ odd-numbered seats then at least $2$ seat in consecutive (odd numbered) seats. Since we have $13 \lt 25$ and $25$ is the "holes" can't be the pigeonhole principle I think.
   Can someone help understand the proof?

Answer (score 2):

Look at it this way. The boys obviously can't be seated consecutively, neither can they be seated with a single gap between them, so the best we can do to see that no one has boys on either side of her/him, with seats numbered from $1$ to $50$ clockwise, starting with boys WLOG is a  pattern of two boys together alternating with two girls together:

- $B_1 B_2\; G_3 G_4\; B_5 B_6\;...B_{45}B_{46}\; G_{47}G_{48}..$

But how can we put the last boy and girl ?
$G_{49}B_{50}B_1B_2$ is unacceptable, as is
$B_{49}G_{50}B_1$

Comment: What is WLOG? I think you are suggesting an alternative answer, but I would like to understand the solution as provided in the book as well

Comment: WLOG is without loss of generality. If you count the number of times the boys are at odd positions in the two alternative ways we tried to place them, you will understand what the book is saying. But in my opinion, it is a rather obscure way of explaining the problem.

Comment: Your answer is a nice logical approach, but how is the pigeonhole principle applied?

Comment: 1. There are 50 pigeonhole with the condition that no person should be sandwiched between two boys. 2. We ponder over the problem and realize that the only way we can attempt this is by alternating two boys-two girls in a sequence. 3. Since after seat 48, two seats will inevitably be vacant, and we find that the two possibilities that are there both fail to satisfy the criteria. So using the pigeonhole principle we have proved that however we seat the people, there will be at least one person sandwiched between two boys.

Comment: You can also see a recent post where many doubts about the pigeonhole principle with different criteria has been simply explained. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4459014/explanation-about-solution-for-selecting-5-out-of-8-integers-and-a-pair-adds

Comment: Isn't your approach proof by contradiction? I.e. that it is impossible to find a configuration that results in two boys-two girls sequence?

Comment: Yes, it is always by contradiction. Generally it is that you can't find  pigeonholes for all the pigeons, here it is  you can't find  *appropriate* pigeon holes.

Comment: "So using the pigeonhole principle we have proved that however we seat the people, there will be at least one person sandwiched between two boys" I still don't understand how the pigeonhole principle was directly applied in the approach you describe.

Answer (score -1):

I think the logic that they are following is by counting a boy for every other odd seat (1,5,9 .. 49) which would give 13. Then you would have to reject the inclusion of the boy in the 49th seat because it would make the person in the 50th seat have a neighbor of two boys (1,49) thus leaving us with a maximum of 12 boys sitting in odd numbered seats. Then the logic that follows is that the maximum number that would be able to sit on even seats should also be 12, and since 12 + 12 is 24 which is less than 25, there must be someone who has two neighbors that are both boys.